# Pgfplots: How to change the axis multiplier symbol

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to define manually the symbol that multiplies the x axis. How to do it so?

As example: Instead of the scientific notation $\cdot 10^2$, I would like to have $\cdot \Delta_x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're actually talking about `pgfplots` (which is built on TikZ, but not the same as TikZ), you need `xtick scale label code/.code={$\cdot \Delta_{x}$}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  domain=0:1e9,samples=2,
  xtick scale label code/.code={$\cdot \Delta_{x}$}
]
\addplot {1};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Or you can turn off any such label, and place a node manually:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
  domain=0:1e9,samples=2,
  xtick scale label code/.code={},
  name=ax
]
\addplot {1};
\end{axis}
\node [below left] at (ax.outer south east) {$\cdot \Delta_{x}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you ! But this seems to replace the $10^i$ value. What happens when this is not present (this is my case)? For instance, in the example you gave, by changing to ..., domain=0:1, samples=2, ...., then the $\Delta_x$ is not produced.

Comment: @FranciscoJoseRomeroHinrichs Well, it was impossible to know from your question that you wanted such a label in all cases. See edit.